# How can I combine two firestore queries, "where", in firestoreConnect?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to create a query to get a firestore collection/doc where userId is equal to the current userId or current userId is equal to contributorsId.

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect((props) => {
    if (!props.auth.uid) return []
    return [
      {
        collection: 'canvases',
        orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc'],
        where: [
          ['userId', '==', props.auth.uid] || ['contributors', 'array-contains', props.auth.uid]
        ],
      }
    ]
  })
)(CanvasSelector);
```

I want it to give me all docs where the statements are true. But it only returns the first one. If I choose to only include either one of the queries ("where") they both work and returns the correct docs.

Comment: Firestore doesn't support logical OR queries.  You have to perform each query separately, and merge their results in the client code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not passing the queries correctly
Try like this -

```
where: [
      ['userId', '==', props.auth.uid],
      ['contributors', 'array-contains', props.auth.uid]
],
```

Also make sure to create a composite index when you use the equality operator (==) with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or array-contains)

Check out how to create one here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: That's an AND, he's looking for an OR